# appropriate layout histograms

Tags: r, histogram, probability

In R I plotted histograms (with the hist-function) of many various distributions. Some of these histograms are quite hardly visible (e.g. points with small frequency in large data). To make it simple I want to view all histogram at once. So are there any methods to zoom into the histogram, maybe zoom a section of the histogram or other things to generate a more appropriate layout. I'm open for new proposals. 
btw I tried to use the package zoom but I failed with this error: no primary function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you would post a minimum reproducible example. 
See here for more: [stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Maybe this could help:

```
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(Hist = rnorm(500), 
             Group = factor(rep(1:5, each = 100)))
```

With `ggplot2` and `plotly`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

g <- ggplot(df, aes(Hist, fill = Group)) + geom_histogram() + facet_wrap(~ Group)
ggplotly(g)
```

Only with `plotly`:

```
library(plotly)
p <- plot_ly(df, x = Hist, group = Group, xaxis = paste0("x", Group), 
      type = "histogram")
p <- subplot(p, nrows = 2)
p
```

You can zoom in and out as you see fit.